# Trying to locate a text element on a page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a dynamically created list of car types, generated on a page.

I want to be able to locate the element by text string , and click on the checkbox next to it (double clicking on the text will produce the same result)

I am currently using :

```
              //select car makes
          Actions action = new Actions(driver);
          action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='MakesList']/label[2]/i"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

But this is very flaky.. doesn't always select the option i want.

So i am trying to get string "ALFA ROMEO":

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,' ALFA ROMEO ')]"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

But i doesn't select the option.

Here is the html :

```
<label class="c-option c-option-search--right u-px u-py-sm u-bb u-m-0 ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in label.buckets" ng-class="{ 'u-bg-faded  u-text-muted  u-disabled' : sc.doc_count[label.id + item.key] == 0 }"><input type="checkbox" name="capMakeName" value="alfaromeo" checklist-value="item" ng-model="checked" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" checklist-model="sc.searchCriteria.selected.makes"> 
    <i class="c-option__checkbox"></i> ALFA ROMEO <span class="u-text-muted u-text-80 ng-binding">(9)</span>
</label>
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: It an angular app. Does you made sure the element is completely loaded before proceeding with click?

Answer (score 3):

In your html there are:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="capMakeName" value="alfaromeo"
```

If your final goal is to click the checkbox, you could use these infos in order to do that:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='capMakeName' and @value='alfaromeo']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first check if elements are visible (or perhaps wait for them to load),

```
driver.findElements( By.xpath("//input[@name='capMakeName' and @value='alfaromeo']" ).size() != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting all the checkboxes as a list, then clicking on the one with the text you want

```
public void clickCheckBoxWithText(String text){
  List<WebElement> checkboxes= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
    for(WebElement checkbox:checkboxes){
        if(checkbox.getText().equals(text)) {
            checkbox.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```